# Can't ping the default gateway

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, router, ping

I recently formatted a mini laptop (Acer aspire one ZG5) and installed Windows XP pro. The PC its working ok but the wifi its not.

The thing is that the WLAN adapter sucessfully negotiate dhcp with the wireless router (ip, gateway and DNS) but is unable to ping the default gateway :S. I checked the router, up and down and nothing seems to be blocking the mini. Turn off both firewalls (windows and the router) and still nothing. The other laptops/devices connected to the router work fine. The mini's LAN card works fine, could connect to internet through it. Finally uninstalled WLAN driver and reinstalled and same thing: no ping. So any clue about whats wrong?

Comment: Do the other devices ping the router? Also, to be clear, the mini is not able to access the Internet, correct? This isn't just a ping problem? I ask this because the ability to ping your gateway is usually something you can enable\disable in the router and some don't support it at all. Also, are you able to access the router setup page from the mini?

Comment: Yes, the gateway does echo reply to other devices and no, mini can not access the internet, or router's setup page. It is like the mini is blocked into the router, except it is not

Comment: Are you sure your IP, Gateway and DNS are correct for your network? Log on to the router interface on another machine and check the addresses against an `ipconfig /all` on the mini. If others work and this one doesn't then I'm sure it's a misconfiguration on the mini... Try also `ipconfig /flushdns`

Comment: Yes im sure, networks parameters (ip, gw, dns) are ok. I can even see (in the router) the list of devices registered and the mini is there, by ip and mac.